# VBA XML return <tag/>

Tags: excel, xml, vba

How would I get VBA to return an XML node that looks like this `<MondayToFriday />`?

I have tried a modified version of this however I want the empty tag not an attribute

```vb
Public Function XMLDupCheck()
    Dim xmlDoc      As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xmlNodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim xmlNode     As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim myNode      As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    ' Create an Instance of the DOMDocument
    Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xmlDoc.async = False

    Dim strPathToXMLFile As String
    ' Load XML information from a file. In this case, Cell C3 of Sheet "XML & DB2 Data" should contain the path of the XML
    'strPathToXMLFile = Sheets("Credentials").Range("C3").Value
    strPathToXMLFile = (Sheet1.[addr] & "308_AKT_PK_306_20200418.xml")
    xmlDoc.validateOnParse = True

    If Not xmlDoc.Load(strPathToXMLFile) Then
        MsgBox "Problem"
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Find out the number of child nodes in the file
    Set xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("*")



    ' Open a new workbook and paste the data

    Worksheets("Map").Select

    Range("A:A").Clear
    Range("B:B").Clear
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select
    r = 2
    c = 1

    Range("A1:B1").Formula = Array("Service Code", "TicketMachineCode")
    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).Select
    For Each xmlNode In xmlNodeList
        For Each myNode In xmlNode.ChildNodes
            If myNode.NodeType = NODE_TEXT Then
                If myNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.BaseName & ":" & xmlNode.nodeName = "TicketMachine:TicketMachineServiceCode" Then
                    Cells(r, c).Value = xmlNode.Text
                    r = r + 1
                End If

            End If

        Next myNode
    Next xmlNode

    r = 2
    c = 2

    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Select
    For Each xmlNode In xmlNodeList
        For Each myNode In xmlNode.ChildNodes
            If myNode.NodeType = NODE_TEXT Then
                If myNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.BaseName & ":" & xmlNode.nodeName = "TicketMachine:JourneyCode" Then
                    Cells(r, c).Value = xmlNode.Text
                    r = r + 1
                End If

            End If

        Next myNode
    Next xmlNode

    r = 2
    c = 3

    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Select


End Function
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TransXChange xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns="http://www.transxchange.org.uk/"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.transxchange.org.uk/ http://www.transxchange.org.uk/schema/2.1/TransXChange_registration.xsd"
              CreationDateTime="2020-04-09T14:05:22"
              ModificationDateTime="2020-04-09T14:05:22"
              RegistrationDocument="true"
              Modification="new"
              RevisionNumber="0"
              FileName="97_AKE_PF_97_20200413.xml"
              SchemaVersion="2.1">
   <VehicleJourney>
      <PrivateCode>5158618</PrivateCode>
      <Operational>
         <Block>
            <Description>7064</Description>
            <BlockNumber>7064</BlockNumber>
         </Block>
         <TicketMachine>
            <TicketMachineServiceCode>97</TicketMachineServiceCode>
            <JourneyCode>6203</JourneyCode>
         </TicketMachine>
      </Operational>
      <OperatingProfile>
         <RegularDayType>
            <DaysOfWeek>
               <MondayToFriday/>
            </DaysOfWeek>
         </RegularDayType>
         <BankHolidayOperation>
            <DaysOfNonOperation>
               <AllBankHolidays/>
            </DaysOfNonOperation>
         </BankHolidayOperation>
      </OperatingProfile>
      <LayoverPoint>
         <Duration>PT1M0S</Duration>
         <Name>Stotfold, The Green (Southbound)</Name>
         <Location>
            <Longitude>-0.225788</Longitude>
            <Latitude>52.020374</Latitude>
         </Location>
      </LayoverPoint>
      <GarageRef>BR</GarageRef>
      <VehicleJourneyCode>5158618</VehicleJourneyCode>
      <ServiceRef>97</ServiceRef>
      <LineRef>2</LineRef>
      <JourneyPatternRef>1</JourneyPatternRef>
      <DepartureTime>07:20:00</DepartureTime>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="60">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>4</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT1M19S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="61">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>5</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT1M41S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="62">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>6</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT1M1S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="63">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>7</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT0M45S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="64">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>8</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT0M48S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="65">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>9</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT1M18S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="66">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>10</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT1M8S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="67">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>11</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT1M10S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="68">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>12</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT1M50S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="69">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>13</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT0M32S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="70">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>14</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT0M36S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="71">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>15</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT1M6S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="72">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>16</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT1M46S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="74">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>18</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT1M19S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="75">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>19</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT0M38S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="76">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>20</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT1M3S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="77">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>21</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="78">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>22</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT0M33S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="79">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>23</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT2M27S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="80">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>24</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT1M22S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="81">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>25</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT2M6S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="82">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>26</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT0M41S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="83">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>27</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT0M39S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="84">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>28</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT0M31S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="85">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>29</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
         <RunTime>PT0M41S</RunTime>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
      <VehicleJourneyTimingLink id="86">
         <JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>30</JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef>
      </VehicleJourneyTimingLink>
   </VehicleJourney>
</TransXChange>
```

Comment: No quotes in the XML but wouldn't display the tag inside the < />

Comment: Please post a small sample of XML and more reproducible VBA code. Data + Code = [MCVE].

Comment: Have updated this post to give more information, the XML is an extract from a TransXchange file (should be ok but have had to heavily remove parts of the XML file, I have included the code that I have used so far as well but need access to the empty or self contained tags for days of the week < tag/>

Comment: Great! Much better. One last thing: what is you desired result? `<MondayToFriday />` is a self-closing element with no text value. So there will be nothing to parse. Please describe or better show your current vs desired results.

Comment: I just need to return the tag so in this case would be MondayToFriday but could be anything eg. MondaytoSaturday, Saturday etc but would always come after <DaysOfWeek>, however there might be multiple tags for Days of week within the XML file, each journey has the days of week tag, the code at the moment returns all of the services and journey codes but need to add in the active days to check for duplicate journey codes as the same journey code could be used on multiple days however if the days of week is different this is ok, hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than parsing XML by hard-coded `NodeName` in advance that can change as you point out, simply iterate through all node names and extract to needed cells. Below parses entire document to first two rows.

Also, for best practices avoid the use of `Select`, `ActiveSheet`, `ActiveWorkbook`, etc. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1422451).

```vb
Public Function XMLDupCheck()
    Dim xmlDoc      As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xmlNodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim strPathToXMLFile As String

    ' INITIALIZE AND LOAD XML DOC
    Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xmlDoc.async = False

    strPathToXMLFile = (Sheet1.[addr] & "308_AKT_PK_306_20200418.xml")
    xmlDoc.validateOnParse = True

    If Not xmlDoc.Load(strPathToXMLFile) Then
        MsgBox "Problem"
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' RETURN LIST OF ALL ELMENTS
    Set xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/*//*")         ' ALL ELEMENTS SKIPS ROOT
    'Set xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("*")   ' ALL ELEMENTS

    ' ASSIGN WORKSHEET
    With Worksheets("Map")
        i = 1

        ' PARSE ALL NODE NAME AND TEXT TO CELLS
        For Each var In xmlNodeList
            .Cells(1, i) = var.SelectSingleNode("*").nodeName
            .Cells(2, i) = var.SelectSingleNode("*").Text

            i = i + 1
        Next var
    End With
End Function
```

**Output**

[image: Excel Output]

If you want to exclude some nodes, incorporate `If` or `Select Case` logic:

```vb
For Each var In xmlNodeList
    Select Case var.nodeName

        Case "VehicleJourney", "VehicleJourneyTimingLink", "JourneyPatternTimingLinkRef", "RunTime"

        Case Else
            .Cells(1, i) = var.nodeName
            .Cells(2, i) = var.Text
            i = i + 1
    End Select
Next var
```

Comment: Cool looks really useful thank you for your help with this

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help!